# Better data structure for a multi map of a hash map

Tags: java, data-structures

The datastructure design I've chosen is proving very awkward to execute, so rather than ask for your expert opinion on how to execute it, I'm hoping you can suggest a more natural data structure for what I'm trying to do, which is as follows.  I'm reading in rows of data.  Each column is a single variable (Animal, Color, Crop, ... - there are 45 of them).  Each row of data has a value for the variable of that column - you don't know the values or the number of rows in advance.

```
Animal  Color   Crop    ...
-------------------------------------
cat     red     oat
cat     blue        hay
dog     blue        oat
bat     blue        corn
cat     red     corn
dog     gray        corn
...     ...     ...
```

When I'm done reading, it should capture each Variable, each value that variable took, and how many times that variable took that value, like so:

```
Animal [cat, 3][dog,2][bat, 1]...
Color [blue, 3][red,2][gray,1]...
Crop [corn,3][oat, 2][hay,1]...
...
```

I've tried several approaches, the closest I've gotten is with a GUAVA multi map of hash maps, like so:

```
Map<String, Integer> eqCnts = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
Multimap<String, Map> ed3Dcnt = HashMultimap.create();
for (int i = 0; i + 1 < header.length; i++) {
    System.out.format("Got a variable of %s\n", tmpStrKey = header[i]);
    ed3Dcnt.put(tmpStrKey, new HashMap<String, Integer>());
 }
```

It seems I've created exactly what I want just fine, but it's extremely awkward and tedious to work with, and also it behaves in mysterious ways (for one thing, even though the "ed3Dcnt.put()" inserted a HashMap, the corresponding ".get()" does not return a HashMap, but rather a Collection, which creates a whole new set of problems.)  Note that I'd like to sort the result on the values, from highest to lowest, but I think I can do that easily enough.

So if you please, a suggestion on a better choice of data structure design? If there isn't a clearly better design choice, how do I use the Collection that the .get() returns, when all I want is the single HashMap that I put in that slot?

Thanks very much - Ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that the best fit is:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> map= new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>();
```

Now, to add *header* inner maps:

```
for (int i = 0; i + 1 < header.length; i++) {
    System.out.format("Got a variable of %s\n", tmpStrKey = header[i]);
    map.put(tmpStrKey, new HashMap<String, Integer>());
}
```

And to increment a value in the inner map:

```
//we are in some for loop
for ( ... ) {
    String columnKey = "animal"; //lets say we are here in the for loop
    for ( ... ) {
        String columnValue = "cat"; //assume we are here
        HashMap<String, Integer> innerMap = map.get(columnKey);

        //increment occurence
        Integer count = innerMap.get(columnValue);
        if (count == null) {
            count = 0;
        }
        innerMap.put(columnValue, ++count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, good answer and clearly laid out as well.  That did the trick for me.  Many thanks also to @slanec and herman respectively, for two very edifying contributions on MultiSet (sorry for the rookie error with the HashMap interface) and the cardinality map concept.

Comment: Note that HashMap isn't an interface, it's one of the subclasses of Map.  I would advise you to use the Map interface for both the map type and the value type: `Map<String, Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>()`.  It should not be necessary to refer to the concrete subtype of Map.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove some of the oddity by replacing your `Map<String, Integer>` by a [Multiset](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset).

[A multiset (or a bag)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) is a set that allows duplicate elements - and counts them. You throw in an apple, a pear, and an apple again. It remembers that it has two apples and a pear. Basically, it's what you imagine under a `Map<String, Integer>` which you just used.

```
Multiset<String> eqCounts = HashMultiset.create();
```

---

> the corresponding ".get()" does not return a HashMap, but rather a
>   Collection

This is because you used a generic 'Multimap' interface. The docs say:

> You rarely use the Multimap interface directly, however; more often
>   you'll use [`ListMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html)or [`SetMultimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap.html), which map keys to a List or a
>   Set respectively.

---

So, to stick to your original design:

- Each column will be a `Multiset<String>` which will store and count your values.
- You'll have a `Map<String, Multiset<String>>` (key is a header, value is the column) where you'll put the columns like this:

  ```
  Map<String, Multiset<String>> columns = Maps.newHashMap();
  for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
      System.out.format("Got a variable of %s\n", headers[i]);
      columns.put(headers[i], HashMultiset.<String>create());
  }
  ```

Read a line and put the values where they belong:

```
String[] values = line.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    columns.get(headers[i]).add(values[i]);
}
```

---

All that said, you can see that the outer `HashMap` is kind of redundant and the whole thing still could be improved (though it's good enough, I think). To improve it more, you can try of these:

1. Use an array of `Multiset` instead of a `HashMap`. Afterall, you know the number of columns beforehand.
2. If you're uncomfortable with creating generic arrays, use a `List.`
3. And probably the best: Create a class `Column` like this:

   ```
   private static class Column {
       private final String header;
       private final Multiset<String> values;

       private Column(String header) {
           this.header = header;
           this.values = HashMultiset.create();
       }
   }
   ```

   And instead of using `String[]` for headers and a `Map<String, Multiset<String>>` for their values, use a `Column[]`. You can create this array in place of creating the `headers` array.

Answer (score 1):

1) The map inside your multimap is commonly referred to as a cardinality map.  For creating a cardinality map from a collection of values, I usually use [CollectionUtils.getCardinalityMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#getCardinalityMap%28java.util.Collection%29) from Apache Commons Collections, although that isn't generified so you'll need one unsafe (but known to be safe) cast.  If you want to build the map using Guava I think you should first put the values for a variable in a `Set<String>` (to get the set of unique values) and then use [Iterables.frequency()](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#frequency%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Object%29) for each value to get the count. (EDIT: or even easier: use `ImmutableMultiset.copyOf(collection)` to get the cardinality map as a `Multiset`)  Anyway, the resulting cardinality map is a `Map<String, Integer` such as you're already using.

2) I don't see why you need a Multimap.  After all you want to map each variable to a cardinality map, so I'd use `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`.
EDIT: or use `Map<String, Multiset<String>>` if you decide to use a Multiset as your cardinality map.

Comment: Apache Commons Collections also have a [`Bag`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/Bag.html) which is an implementation of Multiset (similar to Guava's [`Multiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) ... which essentially is a counting `Map<K, Integer>`)

Comment: I think whether you use a Multiset/Bag or a cardinality map depends on whether you still need the full collection afterwards or not.  E.g. if you're reading millions of rows, you could have a Multiset/Bag with millions of elements (though it may be optimized to not keep multiple references but just keep a count instead).